# How can we pick out features form a JSON string and structure everything in rows and columns?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a small python script that iterates through a bunch of JSON strings and appends everything into a list, liek this.

```
my_list.append(response)
```

Now, I am trying to normalize the list, liek this

```
df_vehicles = json_normalize(my_list)
```

Then, I normalize the results.

```
df_vehicles = pd.json_normalize(df_vehicles['data'])
```

So, ultimately I end up with this.

```
[{'id': '21201', 'name': 'SRW Utility, 4x4', 'latitude': 35.31068751, 'longitude': -80.66177891, 'headingDegrees': 161.2, 'speedMilesPerHour': 0}]
```

I think it's a dataframe of dictionaries. If I run this: `print(type(df_vehicles))`
I get this: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

What's the easiest way to normalize this? I'd like to get features arranged as columns, like this:

```
'id'  'name' 'latitude' 'longitude' etc., etc,
```

I thought it would be something like: `df_vehicles.explode('id')`
When I run that, I get this error: `KeyError: 'id'`

Ultimately, I want to arrange the details under these feature named (columns).

This is 'my_list':

```
{'id': '21201',
    'name': 'SRW Utility, 4x4',
    'externalIds': {'serial': 'X2ND985',
    'gps': [{'time': '2023-01-01T23:57:36.485Z',
      'latitude': 28.82809801,
      'longitude': -81.70075479,
      'headingDegrees': 0,
      'speedMilesPerHour': 0,
      'reverseGeo': {'formattedLocation': '2726 David Walker Drive, Mount Homer, FL, 32726'}
...some more things down here...
```

Comment: Isn't it already normalized?

Comment: Are you iterating through JSON strings, or the results of calling `json.loads()` on each string?

Comment: what's the contents of `my_list` ?

Comment: json.loads() response get appended to 'my_list', like this: my_list.append(response). Is that NOT the right way to do it?

Comment: I just updated the results of 'my_list' in my original post. That's just the first part. It's pretty long! I have a little over 100 features within quotes, like 'id', 'name', 'gps', 'latitude', 'longitude', and so on.

Comment: is your snippet from an item inside `my_list` or is `my_list` itself a dictionary? Anyway, if you can't figure out a way with `json_normalize` (maybe something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh2Yx.png)?), I have a [`flattenObj`](https://pastebin.com/v3Fep60B) function that [**might help**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn3Wm.png)